# ios pressure sensor API

Tags: ios, sensors

In android we can use Sensor `TYPE_PRESSURE` to measure the atmospheric pressure.

Is there any API that is available in iOS for the same purpose. How can this be achieved in iOS?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 3):

No, because no iOS device ships with a barometer. The best you could do would be find some site API that takes GPS co-ordinates and returns the current pressure at ground level there from normal weather observations.

Comment: This is not true any longer.

Answer (score 2):

iOS 8 introduces [Core Motion Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS8.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014205-SW47):

> Core Motion provides two new classes (CMAltimeter and CMAltitudeData)
>   which allow you to access the barometer on the i**Phone 6 and iPhone 6
>   Plus**.